# Displaying a range of images from Instagram

Tags: pagination, instagram

How to display our images from Instagram say 10 per page?

As for now, I see no way to retrieve info only about images we need rather than the full list of all our images (with `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/feed?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`).

Thus every time when displaying a page with images, we need to download the full list of images from Instagram and this seems slow.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Store the URLs returned in a database - then you can check periodically for new images and update accordingly. Now, display the images you want from you DB - this way you have full control over which and how many images to display AND it's a lot faster then going through the API...